# How to return foreach loop in order - fb bot

Tags: php, loops, foreach, bots, messenger

How can I have my foreach loop return the routeTitle and the associated minutes at once rather than have the title first and the minutes after?

My code:

```
<?php
// parameters
$hubVerifyToken = '#######';
$accessToken = "########";

// check token at setup
if ($_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'] === $hubVerifyToken) {
  echo $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
  exit;
}

// handle bot's anwser
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$senderId = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
$messageText = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];


**$stopid = $messageText;
$urlbase = "http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=predictions&a=ttc&stopId=";
$url = $urlbase.$stopid;

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$rt = $xml->predictions;


foreach ($rt as $value) {
   $messagetitles .= $value->attributes()->routeTitle." arriving in ";
    if(isset($value->direction)){
        foreach($value->direction->prediction as $attr){
            foreach($attr->attributes() as $k => $v){
                if($k == 'minutes'){
                    $messageminutes .= $v." min |";
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        $messageminutes = "Error this bus isn't running";
    }
}


if($messageText == "hi") {
    $answer = "Type your Stop ID for the latest times.";
}


$response = [
    'recipient' => [ 'id' => $senderId ],
    'message' => [ 'text' => $messagetitles.$messageminutes]
];**
$ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token='.$accessToken);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($response));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I've attempted : concatenating the strings

```
foreach ($rt as $value) {
   $messagetitles .= $value->attributes()->routeTitle." arriving in ";
    if(isset($value->direction)){
        foreach($value->direction->prediction as $attr){
            foreach($attr->attributes() as $k => $v){
                if($k == 'minutes'){
                    $messageminutes .= $v." min |";
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        $messageminutes = "Error this bus isn't running";
    }
}
```

but this returns all the routeTitles first and then the times separately like this:

> 325-Don Mills arriving in 185-Don Mills Rocket arriving in 25-Don Mills arriving in Error this bus isn't running15 min |39 min |43 min |46 min |

I've also tried adding the $messagetitles variable into $messageminutes like this:

```
 if($k == 'minutes'){
      $messageminutes .= $messagetitles.$v." min |";
 }
```

but this only works if there is just 1 route through that bus stop.

How would I go about returning the routeTitle with each of it's minutes attributes in my loop each time?

XML FEED SAMPLE: [XMLfeed](http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=predictions&a=ttc&stopId=1974)

Comment: It might be useful to see a sample of the xml you are processing

Comment: @RiggsFolly added a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help, I was able to recognize that concatenating the strings was the way to go, but my variables needed some re-arranging. See below for successful output in correct order:

```
foreach ($rt as $value) {
   $messagetitles = $value->attributes()->routeTitle ;
   $messageminutes = "" ;
   $final .= $messagetitles ;

    if(isset($value->direction)){
        $final .=" arriving in ";
        foreach($value->direction->prediction as $attr){


            foreach($attr->attributes() as $k => $v){
                if($k == 'minutes'){
                    $messageminutes .= " ".$v." min,";

                }
            }

        }
    }else{
        $messageminutes = " is currently not available.";
    }
    $final .= $messageminutes ;
    $final .= " | " ;
}
```